# WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_15N vs NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, wgs84, nad83

I recently ran into an issue where my client's project data was presenting correctly in ArcGIS Pro (abutted correctly, correct location relation to aerial), but was shifting several feet when I opened it in ArcMap. I figured out that half of the data was in WGS84 UTM Zone 15, and the other half in NAD83 UTM Zone 15.

I projected everything into NAD83, which solved the projection issues. But I'm wondering what the difference is between these two datasets. I get the gist of coordinate systems, but my understanding was that WGS84 was a geographic coordinate system. Any explanation?

Comment: I think it's something to do with uneven shifts, not that I know much about northern hemisphere coordinate systems, but it seems NAD83 to WGS84 is a problematic transformation. This post https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/converting-nad83-to-wgs84-arcmap-vs-arcpro/td-p/327290 might contain some further information. Note: I would have projected everything to WGS84 it's a more common usage and plays nice with basemaps, open street map and google. Both those coordinate systems are projected but they are based on different geographic coordinate systems (datums).

Comment: NAD 83 and WGS 84 are both geographic coordinate systems.  There are multiple versions of each.  The UTM system divides the world into 60 zones.  Any of the NAD 83 or WGS 84 systems can be projected onto the UTM zones.  For many purposes they can be treated as the same but as you found they do differ.  There are different transformations that can be used to convert from any one to any other again with different results when working at high precision.  So if Pro and ArcMap on the fly applied different transformations you get different shifts.  Always check your transformation method.

Comment: To expand on @John comment. ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop) doesn't automatically set a geographic/datum transformation, but ArcGIS Pro usually does.